# redsys migration in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, sha256

I have a classic asp site with a shop and I have to migrate to the new SHA256 method (in Spain it's Redsys the company who provide the TPV service). It's a Spanish site but I suppose the problem is for everybody.

They have libraries for php and asp.net but no for classic asp.
The problem is when you create the signature. In the manual they say:

1. decode a string with BASE 64
2. Do a 3DES encryption
3. Calculate de HMAC SHA256
4. Encode in BASE 64

Could somebody say where to find the libraries for that (free please)

Comment: Asking for a off site resource or library is off-topic for stack overflow, so don't be surprised if you question is closed.  A library I have used sucesfully for SHA256 is this one. http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2565

Comment: I removed the off site resource request, as I think it's a valid question.  Of course, finding those libraries is piece of cake if you heard of a site called Google, hence the downvote.  The OP might be lazy but other people will run (or have) into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can download and use the RedSysAPI libraries for ASP Classic sites: https://github.com/ictmanagement/redsysHMAC256_API_ASP

**It implements all the required steps for comunicating with RedSys servers**, and you can use the same official documentation because the API interface is the same that RedSysAPI_PHP. You have also examples.

The most important is that you are not required neither to install any ActiveX in your server, nor install PHP.

I hope it will be usefull for you!!

Answer (score 0):

They won't tell you how to calculate the signature (like they did with the SHA1 implementation).  Your only solution will be to use the APIs they provide.  They have PHP, Java and ASP.NET covered but they're still working on the API for classic ASP, so you'll have to wait!

Don't worry about the cut-off date of 23rd of November, they'll keep SHA1 online for a whole lot longer as they're completely missed their own deadlines.